# Libero SoC timing constraints (*.sdc) difference

Tags: fpga, register-transfer-level

After designing RTL I create my_design.sdc file (for constraining clocks, input/output delays, ...) using Synplify pro. When constraints are correct, I click on synthesize and I get another my_design_sdc.sdc file automatically. If I right click on the first one, I can select "Use for synthesis" and "Use for compile" for my_design_sdc.sdc file. What I don't understand is, which file is for what, because after compile and place and route, there is also SmartTime software which takes the my_design_sdc.sdc file.

Q1: What relations are between these two files?

Q2: Does one have to have both of them in complete chain (RTL design to program)?

Q3: If so, how can I be sure that relations between constraints are the same, if SmartTime has different commands than Synplify?

Synplify multicycle constraint definition:

**set_multicycle_path** [-start|-end] [-from {objectList}] [-through {objectList} [-through {objectList} ...]] [-to {objectList}] pathMultiplier[-disable] [-commentcommentString]

SmartTime multicycle constraint definition:

**set_multicycle_path** ncycles [-setup] [-hold] [-from from_list] [–through through_list] [-to to_list]

Also, Synplify uses **define_clock** command for clock constrain definition and SmartTime uses **create_clock**. Those are only few differences.

I'm using:

- Libero SoC v11.8 sp2 (in classic constraint flow view)
- IGLOO2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Synplify auto-generates a smarttime SDC-file based on the clock settings you gave synplify. So that you don't have to define all your clocks twice. As you already figured out, Synplify and Smarttime require slightly different SDC files.

Q2: Depends on your project. Typically you create a SDC file for Synplify, containing basically only clock information. Then you take the auto-generated SDC from synplify and give it to the 'compile' step, together with a third SDC where you define all input/output delays, false paths, and things like that.

Q3: That is what the auto-generated file is for. It allows you to define all the clock settings in only one SDC file.

Keep in mind that the SDC info you give Synplify is typically not terribly important. It just helps Synplify make slightly better area/speed optimization calls sometimes.
The SDC files you give to the compile step are the critical ones. Here your clocks, input/output delays and false paths must be 100% correct.

By the way: Multicycle paths are basically an "expert level mechanism". Very difficult to get those right. It is something which is very rarely used in proper design. Their function is however very frequently misunderstood and misused, causing unstable designs.
In all likelyhood, multi cycle path constraints is not something which you should use in your design.